# Why do old C-style method names continue being used in modern languages?

Tags: naming, languages

I understand that in the earlier days of computing, shorter method names like `printf` made sense, because storage was limited. But why do modern languages like Python and Go still use the less readable names from the C APIs? Why don't they switch to a more readable form like print_format, the same goes for other names. I wouldn't mind having to write `make_directory` instead of `mkdir` in go.

People have suggested that this question has been asked before, but the questions I've found are about whether abbreviated names are bad practice. This question assumes that the answer to this question is usually yes.

Comment: tradition and the people designing the APIs are used to the shorter names so don't think to use anything else

Comment: Specifically for Python's os module (since you mentioned Python and mkdir), the functions use the same short, cryptic names as C because they are little more than wrappers around the C functions, so it make sense to name them the same way. The function name reminds you that the function isn't doing much more than calling the low level C library functions.

Comment: Because they were computer experts for the most part, and they didnt see any advantage to naming it something other than what the *nix command they had been using for 20 years was called?  I really hate questions like this.  You might have a point for something like Go, but Python is ancient in comparison (older than Java, C#, Go, Dart, Javascript...)

Comment: <PEDANT><COMMENT>Its actually a FORTRAN style printf()</COMMENT></PEDANT>

Comment: [Old habits die hard](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Old+habits+die+hard)

Comment: It's a [skeuomorph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph), like the "save" icon is a floppy disk.

Comment: Python is not modern BTW, it was created 22 years ago.

Comment: Just switch to a language that has annoyingly long method names.  I'd become violent if I had to use print_format instead of "printf".  The underscore is especially annoying.  Then again, I'm easily annoyed. :D

Comment: Well, there's a difference between readability and verbosity.

Comment: @Den: Do you define modern by the age or by the relevance in the present industry?

Comment: @Giorgio: Neither would make Python particularly stand out in comparison with C.

Comment: `make_directory` does not carry any more information to the reader than what `mkdir` alerady does. Instead, it carries excess weight(as in, information/meaning per character is lower) and is easily confused with other similar words, because it is composed of two common words unlike `mkdir` which itself has very little chance of being confused with similar words, as such words don't exist. And of course some of us(myself included) simply prefer "unique" names for common entities in the context we operate, it is jargon and makes it easy to communicate with people who are familiar with it.

Comment: One more issue: those names became parts of the common "language" of programmers a long time ago. And just because a new language becomes dominant, or some linguistic constructs become dated, that doesn't mean they disappear overnight - or at all.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Instead of wondering whether they're bad practice, this question assumes writing them is bad practice, and wonders why they are still used.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> But why do modern languages like python and go still use the less readable names from the C apis?

1. Because everyone (in their domain) knows the short names. If you made different names, people would question "what makes this different from `mkdir`?" and generally get confused that stuff isn't where they expect it.
2. Because without auto-complete in an IDE, long names with generally difficult to type characters like _ annoy skilled programmers. Annoyed programmers limit the adoption of a language, meaning designers don't make the names or you never hear about the languages that used them since they never took off.

These are both kinda flimsy arguments of course.

Readable code is known to be better than writable code these days. And having an IDE with auto-complete handles option 2, though there are still people who argue against IDE's as bloat, or a crutch that hinder programmers' abilities. Having an IDE with intellisense (or the equivalent) helps a bunch with #1 as well, though that has the same arguments and works less well in a non-object oriented environment.

Still, these flimsy arguments (and the vagaries of human taste) are enough momentum to keep the trend going.

Comment: Not that flimsy when you consider how quickly a proficient programmer picks up a new dialect (after all, most common languages are just a dialect of LISP or C) with the aid of good documentation (and google). Compare this to domain terminology and TLA's that invade all software, and often poor choice of variable names and poor documentation..... The problem of short names like printf is so far down the list......

Comment: Are you implying that liking long method names negatively correlates with programming skill?

Comment: I understand that this problem is quite far down the list, although functions with written out names are self documenting.

Comment: @congusbongus - not in general, though in certain domains (systems programming, shell scripting) the correlation tends to hold, since the use of IDEs is non-existent there.

Comment: Of course, good old Cobol is the singular wordy exception (not that Cobol is often seen these days).

Comment: #1 isn't flimsy because many of the short names are enshrined in POSIX, a well-known, well-supported standard.  If you're going to mimic the standard's behavior or simply call your system's compliant function by the same name, why not name yours the same way?  That also cuts your documentation down to "Implements [POSIX mkdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html)."

Comment: Some languages can't often be relied on to provide type-dependent autocomplete even in an intelligent IDE (mainly, I'm thinking of Javascript), so in that case I would much rather have shorter methodNames to type out. In C# I'm fine with 'CreateFileAndDirectory'.

Comment: "Because it's always been done that way" is not such a flimsy argument if you put a lot of effort into learning the "standard" names, only to have someone come along and change all of them just because they think the new ones are prettier.

Comment: +1 because your arguments are good, but I completely disagree with your assessment that they are flimsy arguments. I think they are both strong.

Comment: If a method uses the same name as a system utility method, it will generally be expected to have the same behaviors and quirks of that method.  Use of the existing name is good when the behaviors in fact match; use of a different name is better when the behaviors don't.

Answer (score 44):

Why do we continue to use the old Germanic "Albert" as a boys name and not the modern English translation "Shining Hero"?

Because a name is just a label. It's good to give new stuff a meaningful name, but, after long usage the name itself becomes the meaning.

`printf` means something very specific to generations of programmers -- a print function with a template that will use `%2d` to indicate where you want a two digit number printed etc.

On the other hand `print_format` would indicate a function that will somehow format and print some data and you will need to look up the docs to find out how to use it.

Comment: I don't think it's a good analogy. With given names, no one cares about the meaning behind the name because it has nothing to do with the actual person. With the method names it's quite the opposite: the closer the function name is tied to what it does, the better. It's not just a label.

Comment: The point is "Albert" means the guy with freckles who doesn't pay for his beers. The name has been assigned a meaning -- not the other way around!

Comment: Yes, it works that way with _given names_. They are given randomly at birth when no one has even a slightest idea what the person is going to be like. You aren't saying that programmers usually pick a random name for the function, and then make it do something, are you? Even if some do, that's obviously a very poor programming style.

Comment: I'd name my son "Shining Hero".

Comment: Why stop at `print_format` when you could do `print_using_values_substituted_from_arguments`?  And how long before someone gets aggravated typing all of that out and shortens it to `puvsfa`?

Comment: I don't think the analogy is far off. Function names are not given randomly, true, but they are not made fully descriptive either, sort of like referring to a guy you and a friend saw once as "hat guy". And the name `printf` is much more like a given name than it is like a description.

Comment: "a  print function with a template that will use *%2d*" -- don't be ridiculous. Everyone knows that `printf` is for *%0.2f*. I mean, seriously :P. (Also, +1)

Answer (score 20):

It's simple.  Using the traditional names is convenient for millions of experienced programmers.  We know what "mkdir" and "printf" mean.  It is slightly inconvenient for novices, but they soon get over it.

Similarly, most (all?) LISP dialects continue to use "car" and "cdr" instead of "head" and "tail".

Comment: I see the point, but it seams like a long vs short term benefit. If a language changes those names, generations of programmers to come won't have to overcome those hurdles

Comment: True, but if you want adoption of your language you must cater to current programmers, not future programmers. ;-)

Comment: Languages such as C# had opted for the more readable forms of well-known OS method names in their API. [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @bigblind You're a novice once per language, and experienced for as long as you continue using it after that. So which is long term and which is short?

Comment: I mean long term in the sense that you make the learning experience easier for generations to come, which is much longer than the span of any programmer's career.

Comment: For what it's worth, if I had a dollar for every time I typed car instead of cdr or cdr instead of car, I could have retired before I graduated uni.

Comment: Rather than pitching it as "long vs short term", I'd say it's a library designer's dare (willpower) to innovate (breaking existing customs). Both choices have pros and cons.

Comment: `first` and `rest` are often used instead of `car` and `cdr`, but not enough to invalidate your argument.

Answer (score 15):

As others have already said, a lot of these keywords have well established meanings and make it very easy to pickup a new language etc. They are usually shorthand for existing words by omitting some letters (mostly vowels), its not like someone mashed random letters and decided, 'eokjgv' is going to be my function for make_directory.

Shorter names do have actual benefits beyond not having to rely on auto complete:

- Can fit more context into fewer lines or a single screen
- No confusion of trying to reconcile strict computer science meaning with the common language meaning
- Faster disambiguation: if you want to distinguish between `print_formatted_string`, `print_formatted_string_from_file`, `print_string_with_line` it will take far longer than `printf`, `sprintf`, `println`.

Of course, inertia and culture are also massive factors - in common languages, your question is similar to asking: *Why don't people switch to Esperanto instead of English with its confusing grammar and huge vocabulary?*

You can see verbose programs by reading pseudocode : create pseudocode for some small method and see how much volume is added to it, and remember that human short term memory is also a finite quantity.

Answer (score 11):

Because your assumption that "longer names are better readable" is simply not true!

On the contrary, the shorter a name, the higher the chances (other things being equal), that you can identify the name at once, like an icon.

But there's more: the chances that you confuse identifiers that have only a few differences is greater the longer the names are.

As always, there is a middle ground. A public method in an API should not be a single letter, and a temporary local variable must notbe a poem.

Comment: +1 When skimming, people look at the first and last letters of a word, plus the length.

Comment: @Vorac - Actually, when reading novels translated from Russian, where people often have long names that all end in "-ski", I am often confused. Because my brain constructs a most general pattern (or so it seems) to detect those letter clusters that do not make any sense in my language (German). Hence it may happen that "Domedojewski" and "Dokadojurski" are taken for the same person, until suddenly I ask myself: Wait, didn't this Do.*ski pass away two chapters before? How can he appear now again? Chinese novels, OTOH, are easier, because people there have names like Wong, Hang or Lao.

Answer (score 8):

Mandatory xkcd reference:

[image: how standards proliferate]

Let's say you design a language, or a next version of an existing language, and say "let's forget the old C-style names, I have a better idea". You rename mkdir to `make_directory`. Someone else, following the same way of thinking, invents `create_directory`, a third one `create_dir`, the next one `new_directory`, and so on. Now the programmers have a much harder time learning a new language or a new dialect, because instead of instantly recognizing what a command does and what parameters it expects, they have to read through the manual. By not having the same names and structure, it can be much more likely to have a different use or different order of parameters (if I remember correctly, .NET liked to do this in the beginning, some methods had the parameters like `source, destination`, others like `destination, source`). It makes programming either more error-prone, or much slower as the programmer has to read the manual every time he uses a function, because one can never be sure what parameters this function in this language in this version is using.

If **ALL** language designers could agree to change the C-style names for **all** future languages in **exactly** the same way, it might make some sense to do it. Good luck in achieving that!

Common roots and cultural heritage are not there without a reason.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, it's mainly because these are frequently just wrappers around the C calls.  And there is a huge benefit in that being the case (including the short name), basically programmers new to the language know what to expect from it -- what arguments it takes, what side effects it might have, how error conditions are handled.

If I see:

printf ("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10)

I know that (a) this is a right justified, and (b) that it can take up to 5 spaces.  If I see:

```
printf_formatted_string("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10)
```

I have no idea what it means, without looking it up.

Answer (score 4):

The shorter C-style names also convey that although this language is not C; the language has a C heritage and this printf is our take on our venerable ancestors printf function adapted for our language.

C is very much a foundation language and new languages can gain a lot by stating that they are "C-style".

Similarly other languages may purposefully embed the Unix way of doing some tasks and reinforce that by adopting Unix names for doing similar (or identical) things. If you are familiar with the Unix chmod command and implement chmod-like functionality in your language with maybe a similar API, then it might be better to call it chmod in your language rather than change_mode or whatever. It means that you can re-use your Unix experience

Some people believe that what you may do often in a language should have a shorter name.

Answer (score 1):

To do anything useful, all languages need to interact with operating systems but not all languages make calls to OS directly because there's no API defined for these languages. POSIX, for example, only defines API with binding to C and Ada.

A very important part of OS is the C library (libc), which implements the OS' API, at least
after POSIX was defined. POSIX was basically defined based on existing libcs implementations.

If there's no language specific API for a language, then it has to use functions available in libc. It is up to the language designer then to either rename or reuse libc function names and export that as libraries.

I think languages that run on virtual machine (vm as in jvm) shouldn't have the same problem (if it's really a problem).